# Science fiction book where the main character is trying to memorise the face of the person they love

Tags: story-identification, books

I am 99% sure I read this vs. some other media. 99% of the fiction I read falls into science fiction or fantasy so I should be in the right place. Here are the bits I recall.

- I read it in the last few years, no guarantee because I have a LOT of books but that makes it likely to have been published in the last 5 years or so
- The general feel in my memory is science fiction not fantasy but I don't remember any details to support that. Maybe something from L.E. Modesit Jr ?
- The main character was in the middle of a major life event: something like going on a one way trip or losing someone they loved
- They were looking at the person they loved and studying their face. The phrasing was something like "storing up" the ??? of the person to "keep warm in the long years ahead"

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site. As it stands there isn't a lot of detail to go on, and even though you say it's most likely Sci-Fi I can't really see any science fictional elements here. Check out [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and see if you could add in any extra details

Comment: I've tried to give this a bit of a better title, in the future can you try and give more descriptive titles to better match what you are asking.

Comment: I've come across this phrase in a 2012 fantasy/romance novel that I'm reluctant to admit I've read - kind of Mills and Boone with dark magic :-) Does this sound like it could be the book you read? If so I am willing to sacrifice my credibility in the interests of book identification.

Comment: :)  it doesn't sound like my kind of book but it's possible   You can PM me if you want

Comment: @SystemCalls [it was this book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13513660-midnight-s-seduction). But it's a common enough phrase that it's probably been in lots of books.

Comment: A pity you're so sure your read this - this sounds very like the dialogue towards the end of the Warren Beatty version of the movie Heaven Can Wait.

Comment: I appreciate all the help and I have been wracking my brain with no success.  The book is almost certainly in the subset of my books that is in my bedroom; a few dozen.  I think I may have to reread them all.  I will definitely report back when I find it.

Comment: @SystemCalls you might add the titles to the question, see whether it jogs someone's memory. I already checked it wasn't *Second Chance* by Orson Scott Card (there is a lover, there is memory commitment, but how they say, 'close but no cigar').